# Silex mod_rewrite directives not working as expected?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silex

**Directory structure:**

`/webroot/api/.htaccess`
`/webroot/api/web/index.php`

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ web/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**/webroot/api/web/index.php**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->get('/do/stuff', function() use ($app) {
    return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse(array('Test'));
});

$app->run();
```

When I visit the URL http://localhosst/api/do/stuff/ I get a Silex debugging error saying `No route found for "GET /api/do/stuff"`. When I replace the first argument of the router directive to `/api/do/stuff`, the page works appropriately.

Why is it looking for the containing folder `/api/`? I don't want to have to prepend each routing directive with `/api/`, when it's already under that sub-directory.

Comment: Your rewrite base is not correct. If you are hitting your app through /api/do/stuff, you have to put your .htaccess in the webroot and the RewriteBase must be /api/. Also the RewriteRule should be api/web/index.php not index.php. Then you should be able to configure the route in silex with /do/stuff and talk to it through /api/do/stuff

Comment: Ok that works, but my problem is that the webroot has its own set of Rewrite conditions and rules which are conflicting with these.

Comment: So, can you post your .htaccess for webroot? You may need to use a [RewriteCondition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) (check the ```REQUEST_URI```)